# Help finding a sci-fi book with a small space ship

Tags: story-identification

It's a book I read probably sometime between 2003-2007 but it may have been published much earlier, I have a vague feeling it was from the 1990s. I'm in the UK.

Stuff that I remember (sorry it's so vague!):

- I think the cover was dark blue with stars on. It's quite a long book. It's sort of a mystery.
- It's set on a non-Earth colony world and FTL travel is fairly commonplace
- There's a female protagonist
- One of the other characters has (I think) a business which does space exploration
- On his desk he has model space ships, but one of them is an actual alien spaceship with small dead aliens inside
- There are stories about ghosts haunting something, I think it's underwater or on a beach.
- The ghost turns out to be an alien AI which was supposed to protect the little craft but has escaped somehow.
- They went on an exploration mission in the past which went badly and that's how they came back with the tiny ship
- The stars Alnitak and Alnilam are involved - I think that's where they picked it up
- The protagonist steals(?) a spaceship and goes back to where the others originally found the ship to solve the mystery.

I tried searching around for Alnitak and Alnilam but because they're just real star names I haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is [Infinity Beach](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/352778.Infinity_Beach) by Jack McDevitt.

[image: Infinity Beach]

> We are alone, because centuries of SETI (Search for Extra-Terrestrial Intelligence) missions found nothing. Until Dr Kimberly Brandywine seeks her clone-sister and the last lost expedition from the Nine Worlds settled from Earth. The ship's log was faked. She loses her career and her lover, steals a starship, and learns too much truth.

The protagonist is *Kim Brandywine*. The model that turns out to be a real alien starship is called *The Valiant* (that's the name given by the person who has the model - we never learn what the aliens called it).

I have to confess I don't remember much about the book. It does feature the stars Alnitak and Alnilam. The model originally came from a secret voyage to Alnitak, though it takes a while for Kim to discover this as the ships logs have been altered to conceal the details of that mission. The ship was called *The Hunter*, and mission was captained by Kile Tripley, but shortly after the return the crew, including Tripley, vanished in a mysterious explosion. At the time of the story the model is owned by Tripley's son.

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you. It was released here as "Slow Lightning", for some reason. This is cover I remember - https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/513a9F1S5IL._SX310_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg

Comment: That quoted review is dreadful. Clone-sister? Expedition to the 9 worlds? The book is a slow-paced mystery, not a space-opera adventure.

Comment: @OwenReynolds yes, I barely recognised the book from the precis. One of Goodreads' less impressive efforts.